# Trouble passing JavaScript variables to html that is embedded in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

as my title indicates, I am having trouble passing a JavaScript variable to html that is embedded in PHP.
The PHP (html, JavaScript) file works and display’s a document on the browser.
Where I need help is in calling a JavaScript function from the embedded html.
As the document is being is being constructed, that’s when the JavaScript function should be called
so that the document will contain the retrieved JavaScript value.
I have tried various solutions, but they do not work.
I hope my explanation is not too wordy.
If you need to see code, please let me know

Comment: where is your work.  we need to see code please

Comment: I would appreciate if you show us your code, and explain a bit better what you want to do. I couldn't understand you.

Comment: I need to call a function from html as the document is being created.<h3>
                      
             $today     
        <br><br>             
                $custname   <br />  
                $alias      <br /> 
                   
         Notice Type: <var id="asd">$nn</var>
          Call to be made from here          
    </h3>

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think it's going to work the way you hope. The PHP is being run server side, before it is sent to the client. The end user is downloading the constructed html before his or her browser ever starts running the javascript.

Comment: I had limited success by coding the function call inside script tags. But it did not always work

Answer (score 0):

You are trying (by the sounds of it) to run PHP and Javascript at the same time to populate your tags... This isn't going to work.

Three Options:

- Do everything in PHP on the server and send the completed page.
  (most logical)
- Do what you can in PHP, send the page to the client
  and execute an AJAX call on page load to finish the job. (if
  javascript is needed)
- Use Node... (Javascript that runs on the    server - it's a win / win
  situation)

Danny

Comment: Thank you for your options. I was given this PHP project to make this change. The PHP file with embedded HTML and external JavaScript does work and I am aware that PHP executes on a server while HTML and JavaScript execute on the browser. I tried your second option, from solutions I found on google, but they do not work. I am new to PHP so I struggling a bit.